# Getting current file name in Lua

Tags: lua, filenames

How to get current file name without path and .lua?

I tried with:

```
local info = debug.getinfo(1,'S');
print(info.source);
```

and this is what I get:

```
@data/spells/scripts/10lvl/bakurichimacha.lua
@data/spells/scripts/1000lvl/brave sword attack.lua
```

How to delete these parts:

```
@data/spells/scripts/10lvl/ and .lua
@data/spells/scripts/1000lvl/ and .lua
```

To print just bakurichimacha and brave sword attack?

Comment: Strip them out, of course.

Comment: (i.e., find the last `/`, strip that part and before, remove last 4 characters `.lua`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function get_file_name(file)
      return file:match("^.+/(.+)$")
end
```

Comment: Okey, now it prints: bakurichimacha.lua and brave sword attack.lua

Comment: Also, what about Windows?

Comment: @valisstillwithMonica use a character class to match either of the slashes: `[/\\]`

Answer (score 7):

Though the accepted @kingjulian answer seems to be working in most of the cases , it fails for pathless filename arguments.
Eg. aTestFile.lua etc.

I have modified the regex a bit to include these missing scenarios

```
function get_file_name(file)
      return file:match("[^/]*.lua$")
end
```

tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/6wepNs/1)

To get the only file name excluding extension .lua

```
function get_file_name(file)
      local file_name = file:match("[^/]*.lua$")
      return file_name:sub(0, #file_name - 4)
end
```

Comment: Not all file extensions are 3 characters long.

Answer (score 5):

You can use string.match function

```
local filename = function()
  local str = debug.getinfo(2, "S").source:sub(2)
  return str:match("^.*/(.*).lua$") or str
end
print(filename());
```